# Adding Jquery from extension directory in HTML iframe within XUL

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to make a Firefox extension in which a popup panel having an iframe can use an inbuilt js and json script to get data and show it in that panel.

Here's the image of the panel:

[image: Panel image]

My XUL Script is

```
<popupset>
<panel id="TasksPanel"
         type="arrow"
         level="parent"
         alignment="bottomleft">
      <vbox id="taskbox" align="top" width="300" height="300">
        <iframe id="tasks-list" type="chrome" src="chrome://weedo/content/tasks.html" width="300" height="275" />
        <hbox>
        <button label="Add Task" id="panel-add-task"/>
        <button label="Open Page" id="panel-open-weedo"/>
        </hbox>
      </vbox>
</panel>
</popupset>
```

The issue is that adding chrome:/addonname/content/jquery.js doesn't add the jquery in that HTML page (tasks.html). How should I go about adding the jquery in it and also getting JSON data using jquery and show it in the Panel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="chrome://addonname/content/jquery.js"></script>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>JSON Item 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>JSON Item 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

My directory structure is as such

```
-chrome
    --content
        ---tasks.html
        ---overlay.xul
        ---overlay.js
        ---jquery.js
        ---tasks.json
        ---api.js
        ---prefs.js
        ---options.xul
-tasks.html
    --skin
        ---(All my Icons and CSS)
install.rdf
chrome.manifest
```

Edited---

My chrome.manifest file is

```
content addonname  chrome/content/
resource addonname chrome/content/
overlay     chrome://browser/content/browser.xul               chrome://addonname/content/overlay.xul   application={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
overlay     chrome://navigator/content/navigator.xul        chrome://addonname/content/overlay.xul  application={92650c4d-4b8e-4d2a-b7eb-24ecf4f6b63a}
skin    addonname   classic/1.0     chrome/skin/
style       chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul    chrome://addonname/skin/addonname.css
override    chrome://addonname/content/options.xul              chrome://addonname/content/options.xul  application={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384} appversion<=6.*
```

Comment: i suspect the problem is in your manifest file. please post the contents of your chrome.manifest because ```<script src=chrome://...``` should work fine

Comment: @Noit Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question and added the manifest file at the end. Hoping to get an answer :S

Comment: try changing the first line to this ```content addonname ./```

Comment: @Noit Nope, My plugin is not at all working after doing that. `<script src="chrome://...` does work in XUL files, but not in that HTML file :(

Comment: @Noit It seems to have been working with the same old manifest. I tried to open the file using `chrome://addonname/content/overlay.js`, and noticed that it was opening, but when i did the same for `chrome://addonname/content/jquery.js` , it wasn't. I noticed it was a problem with my cache. So I refreshed my explorer window. Restarted the browser dev profile and it seemed to have been working now. Stupid Cache!! Depresses the hell out of me :@

Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: lol no problem cache does that to us. i think chrome.manifest files arent truly restartless yet. like if u install over it, its weird

Comment: Yeah I think you have to restart the browser, even with extension developer mode.